# How can I tell my computer to use multiple cores for gaming?

Tags: multi-core, intel-core-i5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force a single core program to use multi core](https://superuser.com/questions/293809/force-a-single-core-program-to-use-multi-core)

Whenever I play games (specifically Minecraft) on my computer, only one of the cores is being used to run the game, which slows Minecraft down.

I was wondering if there was a way to tell the computer to use all (4) of the cores to run the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general no - software that is multicore aware has to be coded to be multicore aware. I've never known minecraft to be CPU bound however.

There is, however a varient of the [optifine mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-11-optifine-hd-d5-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af/) thats multiprocessor enabled.

Comment: That mod is helping me run Minecaft much better. Thanks a lot! :D